# In the analysis of this insertion sort algorithm, what does the summation mean?

Tags: performance, algorithm, big-o

For this analysis of Insertion Sort, as shown in *Introduction to Algorithms*:

[image]

What does the summation at line 5 indicate? I'm very confused what *tj* is supposed to mean. Why does it not just show that it occurs n*n times or something?

Could someone clarify what it is saying?

Comment: It's an exact formula for the number of times those two comparisons on line 5 are executed. The sum is `O(n^2)`, but that's not its actual value, just a bound.

Comment: What is n?  Is that the length of A?
It looks like t(sub)j is somehow related to the correct position of A(sub)i in A.

Comment: @millimoose What is tj then?

Comment: @DougSmith I believe it stands for "time".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

tj is the number of times the while loop is executed (for the given value of j)

this is a variable that depends on the initial order of the array

Answer (score 1):

The `while loop(iterates i)` is nested inside the `for loop(iterates j)`. Hence for every value of `j` in the outer loop, the `inner loop(i)` iterates for `t_j` times.

`t_j = (number of times while loop iterates for each j)`. Hence total cost overall would be cost summation for all `j` iterations which is `sigma{for all j=2..N}(t_j)`